# Real time processing data using algorithms written in c++

Tags: c++, ios, swift, algorithm, eigen

Here is the scenario:

My swift app collects data from bluetooth and should process them in real-time. These data comes mainly from IMU(gyroscope, magnetometer and accelerometer).

Algorithms that process all of that is going to be written in c++ and utilize some libraries like *Eigen*. How should I approach such problem? From what I've found:

1) put c++ files into my project, write wrapper in objective-c and bridge it to Swift. Also now sure if I can include Eigen in mobile app easily. This would be tedious process I suppose

2) Get all algorithms as library( `.dll`, `.lib` and call it directly from swift, not sure if it's possible)

3) Rewrite all algorithms to Swift, utilize Eigen substitute for Swift, not sure if anything like this exist. Also, this solution is less efficient and would probably fail because of deadlines.

How should I approach such problem? How to solve it in a most efficient way, where I can make use of already exisiting c++ code?

I believe some of you would see this question as opinion based, but I do not know how to state this problem in a way that excludes any ambiguity.

**How to run c++ files that uses Eigen in iOS app written is Swift?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Eigen is a template library. There is no making of library out of it, but using it in compile time. So it depends on the other c++ libraries you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call c++ from Swift. However, you *can* call c++ from objective-c++. And you can call objective-c++ from both Swift and objective-c.

Just make sure that your public-facing `@interface` code (in the `.h` file) contains only objective-c. (no classes, no templates, no namespaces, no including c++ headers).

Your `@implementation` goes in a file with extension `.mm` which will compile as objective-c++ - giving you an objective-c interface with the full use of c++ in the implementation of the Objective-C object.

c++ objects live quite happily as the member variables of an objective-c++ implementation. However, they will be default-constructed then the objc runtime calls `Init`. If you are using objects which don't have default constructors, you will need to either wrap them in a `boost::optional` or a `std::unique_ptr` (etc).

You can them import the objective-c objects into your Swift program.

Full example for anyone who has not done this before:

https://github.com/madmongo1/swift-to-cpp-demo.git

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried already this stuff with wrapping code using objective-c++. Do you think it is possible to use eigen with them?

Comment: @DCDC yes of course. Provided you only call into it from the `.mm` implementation.

Comment: Well, but does that mean I will have to rewrite all code from this algorithms wirtten in c++ into .mm file?

Comment: @DCDC no, you can call c++ functions and objects from the .mm file. You can add c++ files to your project like any other source file. You just can't reference the things in it directly from swift.